# Why wouldn't the Range header work for static resources hosted from a Spring Boot WAR using an embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a Spring Boot 2.0 WAR using WebMVC with an embedded Tomcat 8.5, and I host my static resources from within the WAR.

A request for a static resource that includes a `Range: bytes=0-` fails with HTTP 416 (Range Not Satisfiable), whereas the same request without the `Range` header works fine.

Just for context, the static file in question is an `.mp4` video, which the browser is requesting with the `Range` header because the file is referenced by a `video` element.

Stepping through in the debugger, I see the cause is that `HttpRange.toResourceRegion()` fails to determine the length of the resource. (Or rather, the length returned is `-1`.) The reason is that since the resource's URL is not a file URL it tries opening a connection to the URL and calling `getContentLength()` on the connection, and `WarURLConnection` doesn't override `URLConnection`'s default implementation of returning `-1`.

I want to call this a bug in Spring and/or embedded Tomcat, but if that were the case I feel like someone else would have reported it by now (and I can't find any evidence of that). Am I doing something unusual here?

Or maybe it actually works for everyone else? Maybe there's some magic Spring config that I missed? (I doubt this is related to Spring Boot's auto-configuration, but I should mention here that I have most of that disabled for now as I'm migrating a non-Boot app to Boot.)

I realize I can probably work around the issue by handling this resource request "manually" (and using a custom implementation of `Resource` if necessary), but it seems like I shouldn't have to do that. This seems like something that should just work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've figured it out. It turns out I was doing something slightly different from the way most people probably are, and there is also (what I consider) a bug in Spring Boot that manifests itself in this case.

Specifically, I was hosting these resources from the WAR instead of from the classpath as Spring Boot seems to encourage these days. The fact that the content length can't be determined for `war:` URLs is in my opinion, a bug in Spring Boot and/or embedded Tomcat.

The fix was simply to move the video resources from `src/main/webapp/videos/` to `src/main/resources/static/videos/` and update my resource handler registry config accordingly (e.g. `addResourceLocations("/videos/")` became `addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/videos/")`).

I plan on filing a bug report with Spring Boot, which I'll link to here when I do.

Edit: Here's [the bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14306).